# OAuth соединение сервера и приложения

Tags: oauth, android, php, json

Есть андроид приложение. Как создать OAuth соединение приложения с сервером? Меня интересует как прописать часть что на сервере,  и как потом это принимать в приложении. Есть сервак, там база my sql, написан скрипт на php который генерит jsonы, все вообщем по стандарту. Вообщем пользователь вводит логин пароль так чтоб приложение не видело его, то есть там появляется вэб-вьюха страницы сервера где пользователь вводит свой логин и пароль.  Затем как-то осуществляется это OAuth соединение и сервер предоставляет права на определенные данные приложению и потом уже дальше приложение пользуется данными и функционалом сервера. как-то так. Если у кого-то есть исходники буду рад. Но также буду рад любому совету.
Меня больше интересует подробный процесс передачи секретного ключа и токена. Кто кому передает, и когда.

P.S.
 Но не надо меня отправлять в гугл, я уже там был.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас, как я понял, т.н. 2-legged OAuth, когда Consumer — это приложение на устройстве пользователя, а Service Provider — ваш сайт. Это так, если ваш сайт не запрашивает у другого сайта данные для пользователя (в ином случае ваш сайт становится consumer'ом, а тот, у кого спрашиваете данные — service provider, и все идет более хитро).

В 2-legged схеме взаимоотношения такие:

[image: 2-legged OAuth flow diagram]

Обмен request token'а на access token тут нужен только для того, чтобы это было OAuth'ом. А так это (2-legged) — просто авторизация таким вот странным методом, где пользовательские данные (логин и пароль) обмениваются на токен.

Про «ноги» у OAuth описано тут, если что: http://blog.nerdbank.net/2011/06/what-is-2-legged-oauth.html

tl;dr: Приложение отправляет серверу «я пользователь username, что подтверждаю [паролем, цифровой подписью, мамой клянусь]». В ответ получает request token. Тут же отдает его назад (строго говоря, бесполезное действие, но так надо чтобы это был OAuth) и получает access token. Дальше пользуется им, когда хочет получить доступ к ресурсам.